# Modo interrupción

Tags: c#, manejo-de-memoria

espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo en mi base de datos de mysql una tabla que contiene aproximadamente 18000 registros, cada registro contiene un documento pdf.

Lo que debo hacer es exportar esos pdf a una ruta de la PC, pero cuando intento hacerlo, despues de un rato me lanza el siguiente mensaje.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo que utilizo es el siguiente

```
for (int j = 0; j <= cantidad;) {
    using (GestorDocumento elDocumento = new GestorDocumento()) {
        DataTable miDataTable = new DataTable();
        //se guardan los 10 resultados en un datatable para despues guardarlos en la ruta establesida
        miDataTable = elDocumento.CargarDocumentoTodo(j);

        int filas = miDataTable.Rows.Count;
        if (filas >= 1) {
            byte[] documento = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= filas; i++) {
                documento = (byte[])miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][1];
                File.WriteAllBytes(lblRuta.Text + miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][0].ToString() + ".pdf", documento);
            }
        }
    }
    j = j + 100;
}
```

Comment: Es posible que el problema pueda ser que estás ocupando el hilo principal durante demasiado tiempo. Trata de meter ese código en un `Task` o un `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: No me funcionó amigo, intente con las dos formas y con BackgroundWorker, respaldo un poco mas de documentos pero no todos. Empiezo a creer que es el uso de memoria de proceso, cuando ejecuto mi aplicación en la parte derecha del entorno de desarrollo, aparece un pequeño gráfico de frecuencia y se presentan incrementos en el uso de la memoria.

Comment: Miren mi otra pregunta porfa  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213653/backgroundworker-c

Answer (score 1):

Esa excepción la lanza el depurador del Visual Studio en depuraciones con procesos con tiempos de espera altos. No tiene nada que ver con tu código, puedes comprobarlo intentando poner try/catch y verás que no la captura. Porque la excepción no está en tú codigo.
Simplemente dale a continuar con la depuración y verás que sigue depurando y tu código termina correctamente.

Comment: Es correcto, el problema lo estaba teniendo en la consulta de Mysql, ya optimice el procedimiento almacenado y ahora funciona mucho mejor, Gracias @bsebe