# backgroundworker c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

**Saludos**, espero me puedan ayudar, soy estudiante y ocupo su ayuda por favor.

He formulado otra pregunta pero no tengo mucha acción.
[Modo interrupción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212851/modo-interrupci%C3%B3n?noredirect=1#comment396728_212851)

Trabajo con C#.

Tengo en mi base de datos de MySQL una tabla que contiene varios miles de registros con un campo mediumblob que contiene un pdf, debo extraer todos los pdf a una dirección ya definida.

Para lograrlo voy extrayendo de 100 en 100 los documentos de la BD, lo hago en un  backgroundworker pero después de un rato el sistema falla.

Uso el siguiente código que inicia al dar clic en un botón:

```
private void btnRespaldar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnRespaldar.Text = "Espere...";
        btnRespaldar.Enabled = false;
        pgbDescargarPDF.Visible = true;
        lblPorcent.Visible = true;
        bgwEscribirDoc.RunWorkerAsync(); //inicia el evento del backgroundWorker
    }

// codigo del backgroundWorker
private void bgwEscribirDoc_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // variables del evento
        int cantidad = 0;
        double valPgb = 0;
        double prog = 0;

        // Obtiene la cantidad de registros que contiene mi tabla en la BD
        using (GestorDocumento CDocumento = new GestorDocumento())
        {
            DataTable miDataTable = new DataTable();
            miDataTable = CDocumento.ContarDocumentos();
            cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(miDataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }

        // valPgb funciona para dar un valor de a sumar al progressBar
        valPgb = cantidad / 100;
        valPgb = 100 / valPgb;
        //

        try
        {
            byte[] documento = null;

            // j aumenta de 100 en 100 ya que el procedimiento almacenado que recolecta mis
            // documentos pdf capta solo 100 registros.
            for (int j = 0; j <= cantidad; j = j + 100)
            {

                using (GestorDocumento elDocumento = new GestorDocumento())
                {
                    DataTable miDataTable = new DataTable();
                    //se guardan los 100 resultados en un datatable para despues guardarlos
                    // en la ruta establesida
                    miDataTable = elDocumento.CargarDocumentoTodo(j);

                    int filas = miDataTable.Rows.Count;
                    if (filas >= 1)
                    {
                        // Recorre el datatable y extrae los documentos y los guarda en un
                        // una ruta x (lblRuta.Text)
                        for (int i = 1; i <= filas; i++)
                        {
                            documento = (byte[])miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][1];
                            File.WriteAllBytes(lblRuta.Text + miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][0].ToString() + ".pdf", documento);
                        }
                    }
                miDataTable.Dispose();
                }

                // prog toma el valor que le sera enviado al value del progressBar
                prog = prog+valPgb;
                bgwEscribirDoc.ReportProgress((int)prog);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            frmMensaje frm = new frmMensaje("Ruta de respaldo no definida ", "Precaución", "PRECAUCIÓN");
            frm.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
//indica el progreso del backgroundWorker
private void bgwEscribirDoc_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // progreso del bgw           
        pgbDescargarPDF.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblPorcent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
    }

//cuando termina el backgroundWorker
private void bgwEscribirDoc_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // el trabajo del bgw completado 
        btnRespaldar.Enabled = true;
        btnRespaldar.Text = "Respaldar Documentos";
        pgbDescargarPDF.Visible = false;
        lblPorcent.Visible = false;

        frmMensaje frm2 = new frmMensaje("Documentos respaldados", "Confirmación", "CONFIRMACIÓN");
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Nota:** He notado que el tiempo que dura en extraer el primer paquete de 100 pdf es menor que el tiempo que dura en extraer el segundo paquete de pdf.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna # Proceso representa el proceso de respaldar 100 paquetes, la segunda columna es la cantidad de segundos que tardo el programa en desarrollar ese proceso, la tercera columna representa la diferencia en segundos entre ese proceso y el anterior.

Comment: Como extraes los pdf??? el problema no parece ser de este codigo, tal vez esta mal el proceso de extraccion?

Comment: creo un areglo de byte[]    byte[] documento = null;  y   documento = (byte[])miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][1];
                                File.WriteAllBytes(lblRuta.Text + miDataTable.Rows[i - 1][0].ToString() + ".pdf", documento);

Comment: no no. estoy preguntando, como te llegan los datos desde la base de datos? porque tal vez el problema este haya, y no aca..

Comment: ¿Cuál es la excepción que te da?

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, estoy trabajando en 4 capas, los documentos los recibo un datatable y ahí los guardo, el proceso se da correctamente y guarda aproximadamente 1000 documentos y después cae

Comment: La excepción esta en el link que deje arriba

Comment: la Excepcion  la puede ver aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212851/modo-interrupci%C3%B3n?noredirect=1#comment396728_212851

Comment: Extraigo los datos así    public DataTable CargarDocumentoTodo(int rango)
        {
            miComando = new MySqlCommand();

            miComando.CommandText = "pro_buscarDocumentoTodo";
            miComando.Parameters.Add("@Var_rango", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            miComando.Parameters["@Var_rango"].Value = rango;

            DataSet miDataSet = new DataSet();
            this.AbrirConexion();
            miDataSet = this.SeleccionarInformacion(miComando);
            DataTable miTablaDatos = miDataSet.Tables[0];

            return miTablaDatos;
        }

Comment: En un proyecto me sucedía algo similar, nada más estas utilizando el hilo principal de ejecución y cuando extraes datos el tiempo utilizado es alto y eso causa la excepción que nos estas adjuntando. Podes intentar crear un hilo para ese proceso y captura todas las excepciones y nos comentas haber que paso.

Comment: El código que puse anteriormente esta funcionando con un backgroundWorker, tengo entendido que eso soluciona el problema del hilo principal del sistema que estoy desarrollando.

Comment: cual es el mensaje de error que obtienes cuando falla? no puedes mostrar un form dentro del DoWork(), el uso del frmMensaje debes quitarlo, se loguear a un archivo el exception que recibas, asi analizar porque falla

Comment: Sí eso comentaste según la otra pregunta que dejaste, que habías aplicado **backgroundWorker** pero revisa que lo estés aplicando como se debería. Acá lo hubieses compartido así sería mas fácil encontrar la falla.

Comment: como podría captar el error que me da???  modifique la parte de código  que tenia en la pregunta.

Comment: En la salida de consola de mi entorno de desarrolo me sale:    Excepción producida: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' en MySql.Data.dll

Comment: No. a ver. Algo me huele mal, y del lado del SP y tu DB. Como es el SP? como es tu DB? No estaras haciendo un full scan en cada barrida de datos?

Comment: mi procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro_buscarDocumentoTodo`(
in Var_rango int)
BEGIN
select id_Codigo,Documento from tb_documento LIMIT Var_rango,100;
END

Comment: Creo que ya descubrí mi problema, parece que la consulta de mi procedimiento almacenado no es eficiente CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro_buscarDocumentoTodo`(
in Var_rango int)
BEGIN
select id_Codigo,Documento from tb_documento LIMIT Var_rango,100;
END

Comment: si pudieran ayudarme a optimizar ese procedimiento se los agradezco. tambien hice una pregunta relacionada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/213795/mysql-paginaci%C3%B3n-optimizar-limit