# MySql Paginación Optimizar limit

Tags: mysql, paginación

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una DB de MySql la cual tiene  varios miles de registros con un campo mediumblob que contiene un pdf y requiero sacarlos, para lograrlo lo voy haciendo de 100 en  100, los primeros 100 salen rápido, pero a medida que se va avanzando en la tabla se va haciendo mas lerda la consulta. El procedimiento que uso es el siguiente.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `pro_buscarDocumentoTodo`(
in Var_rango int)
BEGIN
select id_Codigo,Documento from tb_documento  LIMIT Var_rango,100;
END
```

Hice unas pruebas y le di un valor a Var_rango=0 (Cero) y duro 4 segundo, después le di valor de Var_rango=1000 y duro 40 segundos.

He intentado optimizarla con el siguiente select pero no me funciona.

```
select Numero, id_Codigo,Documento from tb_documento  
where Numero > Var_numero order by Numero limit Var_rango,100;
```

¿Como podría optimizar esa consulta?

La tabla tiene la siguiente estructura.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:**

**Numero:** tipo `int` y NO se repite

**id_cCodigo:** tipo `varchar` y es la primary key

Comment: No sera un problema de la db? ese query no parece optimizable de ninguna forma, ya que no hace nada en particular.

Comment: El problema es que al final estás recorriendo la tabla entera. Veo que uno de los campos es una fecha. ¿Podrías sacar los registros por rangos de fechas? Una propuesta podría ser agregarle un índice al campo FechaVBClei y luego obtener los registros por rangos de fechas. Por ejemplo: select Numero, id_Codigo,Documento from tb_documento  
where FechaVBClei >='01/01/2015' and FechaVBClei < '01/01/2016' y así sucesivamente por períodos de tiempo.

Comment: perfecto, me funcionó tu idea, mil gracias @JYass

Comment: Igualmente las gracias a @gbianchi